# ITerm2 Closes Immediately After Opening

Tags: terminal, iterm

My iTerm2 closes right away when I click on the icon in an attempt to open it. I have seen that this is a known issue with iTerm2, but the solutions I found involve editing preferences through the menu. However, I can not access the menu items. Also, I can not resize the window to get the alert to move out of the way so now I can't read the information displayed. Finally, I don't see any error logs. Any ideas?

iTerm2 build 3.3.12 running on Mojave 10.14.6
[image: iTerm2 Error]

Comment: In general see the answer. But I notice that login shell begins with /usr so I don't think you have the default. Perhaps you have removed the shell you use and might be fixed by putting it back

Answer (score 6):

Move the following directories and files somewhere else to back them up.

```
~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2
~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.private.plist
```

See if iTerm2 starts up without crashing.  You may need to redo all your settings or attempt to decipher them from the backed up files. You can open the PLIST files in Xcode in an easy to reference view.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue, and found that by checking the **Suppress this message permanently** box and restarting iTerm, I was able to access the Settings menu again.

Turns out the Settings menu is not grayed out because of the crashing iTerm application, but instead by the dialog message itself. While my terminal window instantly crashed again, iTerm remained open so I could update those settings.

I believe this solution is easier than removing/relocating preference files!

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this upon upgrading my version of macOS, and reinstalling iTerm resolved the problem.